# How auto open infoWindow in google maps API

Tags: javascript, api, maps

i have a problem with my map in my website, I want an InfoWindow to be displayed automatically when I enter the website, please i need you help, I leave the code, i hope you can help me

```
<script>
function initMap() { 
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat . "," . $lng ?>), 
    zoom: 15,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
  }); 
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; 

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
  downloadUrl("xmltiendas.xml", function(data) { 
    var xml = data.responseXML; 
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name"); 
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address"); 
      var horario = markers[i].getAttribute("horario");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type"); 
      var telefono = markers[i].getAttribute("telefono");
      var lada = markers[i].getAttribute("lada");
      var estado = markers[i].getAttribute("estado");
      var link = markers[i].getAttribute("link");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), 
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))); 
       var html = "<div class='infoWindow'><p class='title'>Cell Repair " + name + "</p> <p>" + address + "</p></div>";
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {}; 
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        map: map, 
        position: point, 
        icon: 'images/pin-location-mobo.png'
      }); 
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html); 

    } 
  }); 
} 
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) { 
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infoWindow.setContent(html); 
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
      });  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) { 
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infoWindow.setContent(html); 
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });  
     google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
 }
```

You can always use the google maps trigger event.

> google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');

I added this one after you set the addlistener inside the bindInfoWindow function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Rodrigo0 is this base on the google map store locator api? if im not mistaken.

Comment: thank´s for your answer but It only shows me a location and not all the ones I have on the map, the locations charge an xml file, but it just shows me the first, what could it be?

Comment: @Rodrigo0 what do you really want to accomplish? i thought you want to automatically trigger to open the infowindow.